# Laravel vite production doesn't use https

Tags: laravel, vite

I have laravel 10 and I'm trying to use vite to bundle my assets.

On my local machine running `npm run dev` works fine. But in production using `npm run build` doesn't use https in my blade file, so that I have mixed resources and the browser doesn't load the assets, because the rest of the page is https.

So my question is, what requirements must be set so that vite uses https and not http? Is there some ENV variables that must be set? What else could be the problem?

My vite.config.js:

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: ['resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/app.js'],
            refresh: true,
        }),
    ],
    server: {
        host: true,
        hmr: {
            host: 'localhost'
        }
    },
});
```

package.json:

```js
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "vite",
        "build": "vite build"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "autoprefixer": "^10.4.14",
        "axios": "^1.1.2",
        "laravel-vite-plugin": "^0.7.2",
        "postcss": "^8.4.23",
        "tailwindcss": "^3.3.2",
        "vite": "^4.0.0"
    }
}
```

And my layout.blade.php:

```php
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}" class="antialiased bg-gray-100">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>{{$title ?? __('TEST')}}</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{ asset('favicon.ico') }}">

    @vite(['resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/app.js'])

</head>
<body>
<main>
    {{$slot}}
</main>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: does your server has SSL certificate?

Comment: Yes, it does. The site is running with it.

Answer (score 1):

You might need to set a custom ASSET_URL and set it to the https version of your URL.  This worked for me in Vercel when the html was loading from https but Vite wanted to use http.

Comment: a small note ASSET_URL needs to be created in your .env

Answer (score 0):

I came accross this recently as well, and the reason I had this error is because I had another Laravel project with vite running. This is the log message I had in the project that wasn't loading assets files correctly:

```
:5173/@vite/client:1 
 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
:5173/resources/js/app.js:1 
 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
:5173/resources/css/app.css:1 
 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
```

Simply stopping the `npm run dev` cmd in one of the project was enough to get things running properly again.